# Tunneling git from intranet to remote server

Tags: ssh, git, internal-dns, socks

I have a server I need to develop on outside of my intranet. I try to ssh into the server and setup a proxy that will allow me to clone the repository.

`ssh -D 5555 remote.server`

Then I set my `~/.ssh/config` to

```
Host git.server
    ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:5555 %h %p
```

Where `git.server` is the domain name of my git server on the intranet.

I get the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.server: Name or service not known`

What is happening? Is DNS not being forwarded as well? How can I resolve this?

Comment: OpenSSH does not support DNS forwarding over ProxyCommand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Host git.server
    HostName ${IP-OF-YOUR-GIT-SERVER}
    ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:5555 %h %p
```